# SharePoint Online - Get a list of (Figure out) all non selected choices in a list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, lookup-column, tagging

SharePoint Online environment - I am trying to find a logic for a scenario. I have a Product list and a Product document library. In this list, every list item (Product) is automatically assigned a unique id and we call it Product ID [we used default ID column].

[image: Product List]

For the Product document library every individual document is tagged with a Product ID from the Product list (as a look up column).
[image: Product Doc Lib]
[image: Product Id assigned to documents]

For example - Product ID 1,2 and 3 are tagged with documents Test1, Test2 and Test3 respectively. I want to get the list of not selected or not tagged Product Ids, which in our case are 4 and 5 (as 4,5 are not tagged to any documents)

How to write a logic for this?

All suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: ve you tried setting Unique Values == Yes in the column settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup column in "**Product List**" with the reference list as "**Product document library**" and reference column as "**ProductID (Count Related)**". This column will show you, how many documents are tagged for each item in product list

**Create Lookup Column**:
[image]
**Output in Product List**:
[image]

I hope this will solves your problem :)

Comment: Hello @Shantha Kumar Thambidurai how did you get Product Id (Count Related). I just see Product ID as reference column?

Comment: Ensure, you have selected the document library instead of same list.